# Buddhist Verse Closest To Christian/Jewish Verse

Tags: texts, scripture

What verse that has actually meaning and carries value is similar in both Buddhism and Christianity?

This may be closed as to broad but I think it holds value to have a verse that crosses between such distinct and different religions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *How can I inflict upon another what is displeasing and disagreeable to me? [Veludvareyya Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/sn55.7/en/sujato)*
>
> *And as ye would that men should do to you, do ye also to them likewise. Luke 6:31*

*

> *In the same way others each love themselves, Therefore one who cares for himself should not harm another. [Udana 5.1](https://suttacentral.net/en/ud5.1)*
>
> *‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’ Mark 12:31*

Comment: Love the 2nd one a lot.  Is Ud short for Udana?

Comment: what type of verses are you seeking? there are numerous similar sayings

Comment: These were  good

Answer (score 2):

> Why do you look at the speck of sawdust in your brother’s eye and pay
> no attention to the plank in your own eye? How can you say to your
> brother, ‘Let me take the speck out of your eye,’ when all the time
> there is a plank in your own eye? You hypocrite, first take the plank
> out of your own eye, and then you will see clearly to remove the speck
> from your brother’s eye.
> [Matthew 7:3-5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%207%3A3-5&version=NIV)

> One should not consider the faults of others, nor their doing or not
> doing good or bad deeds. One should consider only whether one has done
> or not done good or bad deeds.
> [Dhammapada 50](https://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=050)

Answer (score 1):

For to every one who has will more be given, and he will have abundance; but from him who has not, even what he has will be taken away. — Matthew 25:29,

If you have a staff, I will give you one.  If you have no staff, I will take it away.  -- Mumonkan Case 44